# Disappearance of `table > tbody:nth-child(1)` in HTML

Tags: html, css, dom

Here is a simple HTML table, and I want to select the ONLY `<tbody>` element.

```html
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Team</td>
                <td>Points</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>B</td>
                <td>21</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Since there is only one `<tbody>`, I thought I can get it using `:nth-child(1)`, but it failed.

```js
> document.querySelectorAll('table > tbody').length /* It worked */
< 1
> document.querySelectorAll('table > tbody:nth-child(1)').length /* It failed */
< 0
> document.querySelectorAll('table > tbody:nth-child(2)').length /* It worked */
< 1
```

Why does `tbody:nth-child(1)` not exist, but meanwhile `tbody:nth-child(2)` exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does tbody:nth-child(1) not exist, but meanwhile tbody:nth-child(2) exists?

The `tbody` element is the *second* child of the `table` element, so `:nth-child(1)` doesn't target it, because it's not the first child, but `:nth-child(2)` does target it, because it's the second child.

An alternative would be to use `tbody:nth-of-type(1)`, because the `tbody` element is the first (and only) of that type of element.

Comment: you can also use: `document.querySelectorAll('table > tbody')[0]` to get tbody